# SELECT on a unique column (DISTINCT?)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query giving me the follwing table (ORDER BY b):

```
a  b    c
1  100  x1
1  90   x2
2  85   y1
1  80   x3
2  75   y2
2  70   y3
1  65   x4
```

I want to have the following output:

```
a  b   c
1  100 x1
2  85  y1
```

So that the value in a is unique, but it should be the row with b as the highest value. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you devaluate this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (a) t.*
from mytable t
order by a, b desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner join`

```
select * from TableName as t1
  inner join (
  select a,max(b) as b from TableName
  group by a
) as sub_table on sub_table.a = t1.a and sub_table.b = t1.b
```